# Simplify this limit

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Is there anyway I can simplify this limit?

> $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_a^b \dfrac{\epsilon f(t) dt}{(t-x)^2 +\epsilon^2 }$$ 
>   where $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: What do think the limit is?

Comment: MVT is useful here.

Comment: The solution of your problem depends on the course you are studying now.

Comment: @science, you mean limit depends on the math course op is taking?

Comment: @abel: In other words what's the goal from this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral from $a$ to $b$ breaks into two pieces:  $\int_a^b=\int_a^x+\int_x^b$.  Let's consider the second of these.  Using the change of variables $t-x=\epsilon u$ (as in abel's answer), we have

$$\int_x^b{\epsilon f(t)dt\over(t-x)^2+\epsilon^2}=\int_0^{(b-x)/\epsilon}{f(x+\epsilon u)du\over u^2+1}$$

Now if $x=b$, this integral is clearly $0$ for all $\epsilon\not=0$.  If $b\lt x$, on the other hand, the integral converges to

$$\int_0^\infty{f(x)du\over u^2+1}={\pi\over2}f(x)$$

as $\epsilon\to0$. A similar argument applies to the piece from $a$ to $x$, so overall we get the limit $\pi f(x)$ if $a\lt x\lt b$ and ${\pi\over2}f(x)$ if $x=a$ or $b$.

I hasten to point out that a bit of care actually needs to be taken to formally justify simultaneously letting $(b-x)/\epsilon\to\infty$ and $f(x+\epsilon u)\to f(x)$.  I'm glossing over it partly out of laziness, but I'll flesh it out if the OP requests.

Comment: No need to flesh out it's just $f(x+\epsilon u)\chi_{[0,\frac{b-x}{\epsilon})}du \to f(x)du$ and DC. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you may need to flesh that out for me.... ;-)

Comment: In case someone stumbles here: Define $d\mu=d(\tan^{-1})$. 
$f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ $\implies f(x) \le M \in L^1(\mu)$. By dominated convergence $\int_0^{\infty}f(x+\epsilon t)\chi_{[0,\frac{b-x}{\epsilon})}d\mu (t) \to \int_0^{\infty}f(x)d\mu (t)$

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, so by MVT, there exists a $c \in [a,b]$ such that:

$$\int_a^b \dfrac{\epsilon f(t) dt}{(t-x)^2 +\epsilon^2 } = f(c)\int_a^b \dfrac{\epsilon}{(t-x)^2 +\epsilon^2 }dt$$

But:

$$\int_a^b \dfrac{\epsilon}{(t-x)^2 +\epsilon^2 }dt = \cdots = \arctan(\frac{b-x}{\epsilon}) - \arctan(\frac{a-x}{\epsilon})$$

The limit eventually becomes: $\pi f(c)$ if $x \in ]a,b[$, $\frac{\pi}{2}f(c)$ if $x = a$ or $x = b$,

Comment: I can't see how the part with the MVT works. What's the function your'e differentiating?

Comment: I'm using MVT for integrals. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem